# Loading message and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
$(function() {
    $(".message").hide();

    function simulate_ajax_call()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/json/",
            success: function(){
                alert("done");
                $(".message").empty().html("done");
                $(".message").delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    }

    $('.button').click(function() {
        $(".message").fadeIn(500);
        setTimeout("simulate_ajax_call()", 5000);
    });
});
```

With the following HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="button" class="button" />
<div class="message">loading...</div>
```

For some reason the `setTimeout` part is not working.  i.e. it does not seem to call the function after 5000ms.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/kHEVa/).

Comment: Basic debugging first. You are 100% sure this is because of the timeout and not because of a problem in the Ajax call?

Comment: Anyway, whatever you do, you should be using `setTimeout(function() { simulate_ajax_call();}, 5000);`

Comment: @Pekka Or `setTimeout(simulate_ajax_call, 5000);` - No need to wrap a function invocation within another function. Functions are [first-class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), remember? :P

Comment: @Jacob fair enough! I tend to prefer the function notation though, in case I need to add something (like a parameter) later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
setTimeout("simulate_ajax_call()", 5000);
```

with:

```
setTimeout(simulate_ajax_call, 5000);
```

### [Check out the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kHEVa/1/)

---

You should avoid putting `()` at the end of the function name because otherwise *[it gets called/run immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983150/jquery-dollar-sign-as-function-argument/4983176#4983176)* :)

Answer (score 4):

[You need to drop the quotes and the parenthesis](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/kHEVa/3/).

Doing `setTimeout("simulate_ajax_call()", 5000)` is equivalent of `eval()`ing that code, which is automatically running the function.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` `eval`s its string argument in the global scope, but `simulate_ajax_call` is declared in a nested scope, so the `eval` can't find it in order to invoke it.

As the other two answers point out the best way to resolve the issue is to use the function-passing version of `setTimeout`, but being careful to remove the parentheses, because you don't want to accidentally invoke the function immediately.

Your code would probably have worked had you declared `simulate_ajax_call` at the global scope. The parentheses would have been correct in this case, although the string version of `setTimeout` is still a bad idea in general.