# Module Pattern - why is JQuery passed in as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I understand the module pattern, but why do some examples pass JQuery in as a parameter like this:

```
Namespace.AppName = (function ($) {
     // Code Here
})(jQuery);
```

If I don't pass in JQuery I can still use the Jquery library just fine by making $() calls inside the module.  So why do some people do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery dollar sign ($) as function argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983150/jquery-dollar-sign-as-function-argument)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea here is that you pass `jQuery` as `$` to the inside function, making sure that the `$` IS jQuery. This is commonly used to protect code that uses `$` especially when using jQuery along with other libraries that use `$` like mootools.

---

example, if you had this code in the `<head>`

```
<!--load jQuery-->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    //"$" is jQuery
    //"jQuery" is jQuery 
</script>

<!--load another library-->
<script src="anotherlibrary.js"></script>

<script>
    //"$" is the other library
    //"jQuery" is jQuery 

    //out here, jQuery code that uses "$" breaks

    (function($){
        //"$" is jQuery
        //"jQuery" is jQuery (from the outside scope)

        //in here, jquery code that uses "$" is safe

    }(jQuery));

</script>
```

Comment: "$" is the other library  when the anotherlibrary.js defined $ as a global. I think

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the $ 'safely'. Most developers are more comfortable with the '$' instead of jQuery.

When using the $ as a global, it may conflict with other JS libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This is so you can use $ as s shortcut for jQuery. This can sometimes collide with other libraries if you don't encapsulate it like this.

Answer (score 0):

This if for making sure that your namespace/scope uses $ as `jQuery` and not other JS libraries like Prototype, which uses $, too.