# trying to map someFunction.jQuery to "$"

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I found a function ([via this person's github](http://mths.be/unsafewindow)) that I might use in my script that mimics the functionality of an API object.

Here's the relevant code from the link:

```
unsafeWindow = (function() {
    var e1 = document.createElement('p')
    e1.setAttribute('onclick', 'return window;');
    return e1.onclick();
})();
```

Where the poster says you can use  the function in the format `unsafeWindow.jQuery`

Now, I want to be able to use `$` instead of the jQuery keyword elsewhere in my code. I tried learning from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983150/jquery-dollar-sign-as-function-argument) to simplify it and re-wrote the code like so:

```
(function($){
    var e1 = document.createElement('p')
    e1.setAttribute('onclick', 'return window;');
    return e1.onclick();
})(jQuery);
```

But it didn't work. I guess I could just try something like `$ = unsafeWindow.jQuery` in order to map to the `$`, but I wanted to try to do it in the format seen above.

Comment: Are you really making an extension?  That is, do you have a `manifest.json`?  If so, then this is a `content-script` question, not a `userscripts` question.  PS: [making a userscript into a full-featured content script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259212/331508) is easy.

Comment: I just changed it for you.  What you are doing, currently, *is* a userscript and not what most would consider an extension (But there is a lot of overlap in Chrome).

Comment: Since you are starting out, I suggest you install the Tampermonkey extension.  Then you can write one script that will almost always work the same in both GM+Firefox and Tampermonkey+Chrome.  Tampermonkey has a lot of other advantages over ordinary Chrome userscripts.

Answer (score 1):

You would map `$` to `unsafeWindow.jQuery` like so:

```
unsafeWindow    = ( function () {
    var dummyElem   = document.createElement('p');
    dummyElem.setAttribute ('onclick', 'return window;');
    return dummyElem.onclick ();
} ) ();

var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;

// Now you can use the page's jQuery. EG:
$("body").append ('<p>Content added by unsafeWindow.jQuery</p>');
```

But keep in mind:

1. **This is a Hack**, and it will probably stop working around Chrome version 28.
2. It may still fail due to a **race condition** about when userscripts fire.  To fix that, add `// @run-at document-end` to the userscript's metadata block.
3. **Don't do things this way!**  It will only cause grief, side effects and maintenance headaches.

   For ***userscripts:*** use [this technique (best cross-browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508)  or  [this technique (relies on page's jQuery, but the example shows how to use GM_ functions too)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379215/331508).

   For ***full extensions*** or ***content scripts:***, use [this technique (use the `manifest.json` and keep everything properly sandboxed)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947636/331508).

Comment: In all 3 methods I linked, you don't use `unsafeWindow` at all.  You should never use `unsafeWindow` for a library like jQuery.  And you should avoid using `unsafeWindow` at all, if you can help it.  `unsafeWindow` is for those pretty-rare scenarios when you can't figure any other solution but to use a page's *unique* JavaScript object, and when the use seems too trivial to use script injection.  The `manifest.json` approach gives your script its own copy of jQuery, removing the need for `unsafeWindow` and providing a host of other benefits (beyond scope of this question).

Comment: But there's my problem now, for the purposes of my script I need to access and use a certain website's unique JavaScript object(s). How could I do so if I'm not using `unsafeWindow` or a function that mimics it? (I'm sorry if this seems like a redundant question or silly even (my own research only yielded `unsafeWindow` as a means of accessing these hidden unique objects), you're being very helpful and I appreciate your time).

Comment: Open a new question and give ***specifics*** of the both the code you are trying to use, your real goal, and what you have tried. *This* question is answered and comments are not designed for endless follow-up or tangential questions.