# meaning of $ sign in jquery document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally when I am writing my jquery code I do something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // some code
});
```

I was looking at some code online and I noticed that the author did this

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   // some code
});
```

What is the use of the `$` as the function parameter

Comment: Look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - it's pretty clearly explained in the `Aliasing the jQuery Namespace` section

Comment: This explains it all - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1719-jQuery-s-Passes-Itself-As-An-Argument-To-The-Ready-Event-Callback.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983150/jquery-dollar-sign-as-function-argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery calls the callback function with `jQuery` as the first argument. Javascript doesn't require you to define parameters that will be passed to your function so it's usually left out if it's not needed.

Here it seems weird because the author is already relying on `$` being jQuery - you would normally expect it to be along the lines of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $ works here even if someone changed the global `$`
    // this breaks down if someone changed jQuery too but that's far less likely
});
```

Comment: It's also good to note that `jQuery(function($){})` is equivalent to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})`.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function is the value of jQuery or of $. It serves as a namespace so we can call it "The global jQuery object."

Answer (score 0):

Buddy Please jquery documentation.Its well written and easy to understand . Any way i will tell you what is the $ sign. $ is a shortcut to the jQuery function. .

```
 **$**(document).ready(function() {

  // statements

 });
```

Here **$** represents jquery .You can use **jquery**  instead of **$** sign..

See this link [Click here](http://docs.jquery.com/%24)