# How can I use jQuery on Magento 1.9.0.1 rwd theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.9.1

I noticed Magento 1.9.0.1 rwd theme now include jQuery library and use "jQuery.noConflict();" associated on "$j" token on default.

First, I'ld like to use google CDN jQuery library instead of local jQuery library.

As second, how can run my jQuery code?

For example, I tried to insert in minicart.phtml:

```
    .....
       $_cartQty = 0;
    }
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $('#header-cart').hide();
    });
</script>


<a href="#header-cart" class="skip-link skip-cart <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    ........
```

Also, I tried to use add my code at the end of app.js:

```
.....
};

$j(document).ready(function() {
    ProductMediaManager.init();
});

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-cart').hide();
});
```

but no effect. Where I wrong? How can I run my code in a separate file in app/js folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “First, I'ld like to use google CDN jQuery library instead of local jQuery library.”

You should research more before asking easy questions, the following is taken from [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3625/3408) and [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12978/3408).  Overall I think it's not worth the extra effort just to rely on a 3rd party.

In your theme's `local.xml` layout file add this.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</name></action>
        <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery||document.write('<script src="/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">\x3c/script>');</script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

---

> “As second, how can run my jQuery code?”
>
> ```
> $j(document).ready(function() {
>     $('#header-cart').hide();
> });
> ```

Here you know you must use `$j` instead of `$` but you have forgotten that on the 2nd line!  There are many ways to change it,

1. Use `$j` *everywhere:*

   ```
   $j(document).ready(function() {
       $j('#header-cart').hide();
   });
   ```
2. Rename `$j` using [the function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4983150/471559):

   ```
   $j(document).ready(function($) {
       // $ is different inside this function only
       $('#header-cart').hide();
   });
   ```
3. Use Prototype instead:

   ```
   // $j is alias for jQuery
   $j(document).ready(function() {
       // $ is Prototype alias for document.getElementById
       $('header-cart').hide();
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Apart discuss if is better use local library or hosted on google CDN that anyway could be an interesting debate (at least for me), I posted this question because I read that with new Magento 1.9.x rwd theme things are changed and jQuery was "integrated" by default. I saw those post before post the question but they can't help me (are dated 2010/2013, maybe something is changed?). In code example, as you rightly said, I forgot to report "j" on second instruction but, as I tried before, still doesn't work and this is why I posted the question.

Comment: _Mea culpa_. Too fast and too furious (or too dumb is most correct in this case). I confused #header-cart of <div> with #header-cart link of <a> so I expected it hide <a> element while it was hiding div element (minicart content shown on <a> click). I deserve another point less.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflicts with prototype.js you'll need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`

For example instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // do something
});
```

Write:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // do something
});
```